# New tab button - UIWindowScene and macOS Catalyst

Tags: swift, macos, mac-catalyst

Is it possible to add a "New Tab" button to the tabBar, like Safari and Finder has? My app is a Mac Catalyst app and has support for multiple windows, but to open new windows the user has to select it from the menu bar or use keyboard shortcuts.

The idea is to have this built-in Tab Bar work much like https://github.com/stuffmc/TabbedViews does.

[image].

The built-in one has:

- No `+` button (and no *New Tab* menu either)
- Only the option to display the full display of a window. This one can display the Tab Bar anywhere, and especially also on iOS.

This one though has no support yet for *Move Tab to New Window* and of course one need not to forget to remove *Merge All Windows*, otherwise both will conflict.

Comment: I wonder why this has been closed. It couldn't be clearer to me. So @infero I was wondering exactly the same thing today! I actually built my own Tab Bar for SwiftUI, mostly because I missed that "Merge All Windows" ;) but after reviewing what the built-in system does. my version gives much more flexibility (and a "+" button!). It doesn't support "Move Tab to new Window yet" though. https://github.com/stuffmc/TabbedViews